# Perl: Don't print any lines that are duplicates

Tags: perl

What is a Perl one-liner to only print those lines that only ever appear once (that is, do not print if it appears more than once--the truly unique lines)?

For example, if I have a file that contains duplicate lines:

```
line1
line2
line2
line3
line1
line4
line5
```

The output should be:

```
line3
line4
line5
```

I can do `perl -ne 'print if $a{$_}++' file` to see only the lines that are duplicates...

```
line2
line1
```

I can swap the `if` for its antonym, `unless`, and see only one occurrence of each line in the file...

```
perl -ne 'print unless $a{$_}++' file
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

I'm assuming I have to slurp the entire file in and process it using single `\n` delimiters for each line, maybe into a hash?  Just not sure how to do that.

Comment: Do you need to make it work with perl? If you are on unix try sort -u file > new_file instead.

Comment: @NepCoder `sort -u` gives me the same output as my last above (i.e., lines 1-5).  I need to exclude lines that every appear more than once all together.

Comment: Do the lines have to stay in the same order?

Comment: @Tanktalus Sorry, yes if possible.  Playing off of @NepCoder 's comment, I could get what I have as the desired output by `sort file | uniq -u` but I'm not keeping the original order of the file

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only know if a line is unique after you've read all the lines, so you can't possibly start printing before you've reached the end of the file!

```
# Varying order

perl -nle'++$lines{$_}; END { print for grep $lines{$_}==1, keys %lines; }' file
```

or

```
# Sorted

perl -nle'++$lines{$_}; END { print for sort grep $lines{$_}==1, keys %lines; }' file
```

or

```
# Original order

perl -nle'
   if ( my $orig_line_num = $line_nums_by_line{$_} ) {
      $lines_by_line_num[$orig_line_num] = undef;
   } else {
      $lines_by_line_num[$.] = $_;
      $line_nums_by_line{$_} = $.;
   }

   END { print for grep defined, @lines_by_line_num; }
' file
```

Comment: @ikegami thanks for the detailed answers!  These are right down the path I was thinking.  Looks like the first two perl one-liners are duplicates?  When I run them or the sort command, I get all uniq lines (so 1-5) vs. the desired 3,4,and 5.  I'm not getting an output from the last example, but looking at it more closely now.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it:

```
perl -e'@a=<>; $d{$_}++ for @a; print grep {$d{$_}<2} @a' file
```

Comment: If you want to handle a lack of newline on the last line: `perl -le'chomp( @a=<> ); $d{$_}++ for @a; print for grep {$d{$_}<2} @a' file`

Comment: @KoshVery pretty clever answer!  The use of grep to pull out only values equaling `1` is pretty sharp!  Well done.  another great answer!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, to filter the file in this way and keep the lines in order you need to either read through the file twice or to store line number information while you read

This one-liner seems the best option

```
perl -e '@a = @ARGV; ++$c{$_} while <>; @ARGV = @a; $c{$_} == 1 and print while <>;'  myfile.txt
```

#### output

```
line3
line4
line5
```

This is a slightly shorter alternative, but it uses double the amount of memory to store the file data

```
perl -e '@l = <>; ++$c{$_} for @l; $c{$_} == 1 and print for @l;' myfile.txt
```

Comment: thanks for the response.  I agree, I like the first one-liner a lot.  Copy the file into an array, keep track of the number of occurrences into the `c` hash, incrementing the key when seeing a duplicate. Then use the second array (cp `@a` back to `@ARGV` (thus less memory)? and pull the key value pairs from the hash who's value is only equal to `1`.  (at least I think I'm interpreting that correctly.) The second option reiterates through the same array twice over thus using twice the memory.  Very good!  I wish i could select multiple correct answers!

Answer (score 1):

This should work although it's a Unix solution:

```
sort file1|uniq -u
```

*line3

line4

line5*

where file1 has:
*line1

line2

line2

line3

line1

line4

line5*

The -u option of the uniq command lists only non-duplicate entries, and uniq works on a sorted output